# VBA : For each loop to delete if empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops

First of all thanks for your help.
I tried to do some code doing the following : go throught the different worksheets in the workbook , find the latest non empty cells in the first column for each sheet and delete rows for empty cells.

```
Sub DeletedBlanks()
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim i as Integer
Dim lrow as Integer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
 For i = lrow to 1 Step -1
  If Trim(Cells(i,1))="" Then
   Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
 Next i 
Next 
End Sub
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.. To test it I created 3 arrays on 3 sheets but everything has been deleted or just a part.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to put `ws.` in front of ALL `Cells()` and `Rows()` so the code uses that sheet and not the active sheet.

Comment: You need to qualify `Cells` and `Rows`, else VBA will assume the *ActiveSheet*. Write `ws.Trim(Cells(i,1)` and `ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete` (or use an `With` statement).

Comment: Many thanks to all of you ! ws.Trim(Cells(i,1)) --> Trim(ws.Cells(i,1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues in that procedure, all of which [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) can warn about:

```vb
Dim i as Integer
Dim lrow as Integer
```

`Integer` is a 16-bit signed integer type, which makes its maximum legal value 2^15-1, or 32,767. Problem is, an Excel worksheet can have many times more rows than that, so using an `Integer` variable to count the rows of a worksheet will inevitably turn into *Overflow* errors given enough data. The [IntegerDataType](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/IntegerDataType) inspection flags these declarations and provides a quick-fix to change them to `Long` (32-bit signed integers) instead.

But that is not what brought you here.

```vb
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Assuming the code is living in a standard module and not a worksheet module, here `Rows.Count` is returning the number of rows *on whatever the ActiveSheet is*. That is *usually* not a problem, because *normally* all sheets in a workbook have the same number of rows.

```vb
If Trim(Cells(i,1))="" Then
```

This is different. Now we're looking at a cell on row `i`, but not on the `ws` sheet; unqualified, `Cells` is also *implicitly* referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is. The [ImplicitActiveSheetReference](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) Rubberduck inspection flags these implicitly-qualified member calls.

Same with `Rows` here:

```vb
Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

We're deleting row `i` on `ActiveSheet`, not `ws`.

As @FunThomas said in a comment:

> Write `ws.Trim(Cells(i,1)` and `ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete`

There's a typo here, that should have read as follows:

> Write `Trim(ws.Cells(i,1)` and `ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete`

In other words this should work as intended:

```vb
Sub DeletedBlanks()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim i as Long
    Dim lrow as Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lrow to 1 Step -1
            If Trim(ws.Cells(i,1))="" Then
                ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i 
    Next 
End Sub
```